# Where can I find gtkmm/overlay.h?

Tags: overlay, gtkmm

I'm using [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Overlay.html) page to create an overlay widget but I don't have gtkmm/overlay.h

libgtkmm-3.0-dev (v3.10.1) is installed. I can't seem to find overlay.h in my install or even the latest unstable source (v3.11.10)

Any ideas where I can find this?

Comment: It should definitely be there, if any of the headers are installed. What distro are you using?

It isn't in the source tarball because it's generated during the build. But overlay.hg will be in the source tarball.

Comment: @murrayc I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. "dpkg -L libgtkmm-3.0-dev" tells me there are a whole lot of header files in "/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0/gtkmm". I sense I must be doing something wrong. I can't find overlay.hg in [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gtkmm/3.11/gtkmm-3.11.10.tar.xz) either.

Comment: Now I understand. It's our (gtkmm) mistake, not yours. I've added an answer to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Since gtkmm 3.2" text in that documentation for Gtk::Overlay is wrong. It was actually added in gtkmm 3.14:
https://git.gnome.org/browse/gtkmm/tree/NEWS

I have corrected it in gtkmm's git, so it will be correct online when we do a release. Sorry about that.

However, GtkOverlay has been in GTK+ since GTK+ 3.2, so you can use that part of the C API from your C++ code, by using gobj() and Glib::wrap():
http://www.gtkmm.org/docs/libgnomedbmm-3.0/docs/tutorial/html/ch03.html#sec-basics-gobj-and-wrap